# Adding events to elements inside loop - JScript/Closures

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I'm building a list of buttons and I want each one to trigger the **addForm()** function with the current **members[member].id**.

But it happens that only the last button will fire the event.

I know it has something to do with closures and as you can see I have adapted the function to use this pattern.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function displayConnections(connections) {
    /*(...)*/

    for (var member in members) {

        connectionsDiv.innerHTML += "<p>" + members[member].firstName + " " + members[member].lastName
        + " ID: " + members[member].id;

        btn = document.createElement("input");
        btn.setAttribute("type","button");
        btn.setAttribute("value","Send Message");
        btn.setAttribute("id",members[member].id);

        btn.onclick = function (id) {
            return function () {
                addForm(id);
            };
        }(members[member].id);

        connectionsDiv.appendChild(btn);

    }     
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First, remember you are not writing C# or Java.  The `for (var ... in ...)` structure does not iterate a collection.  You should always check `hasOwnProperty` to see if the property name belongs to the object itself:

```
if (!members.hasOwnProperty(member)) continue;
```

Then check to make sure that the property value is an object and not a function etc.

Second, your variable `btn` is lacking a `var` declaration.  You are creating a *global* variable called `btn`, not a variable local to your function.

Next, you have a typo mistake in your original code.  Your original code actually is interpreted this way (thanks to JavaScript's auto-semicolon-insertion *feature*!):

```
btn.onclick = function (id) {
    return function () {
        addForm(id);     <-- this id is now the click event's event object, not what you want
    };
};
(members[member].id);   <-- this line will have no side effect
```

In order to run your program in your original style, you need to bracket the function definition:

```
btn.onclick = (function (id) {
    return function () {
        addForm(id);
    };
})(members[member].id);
```

Comment: I think you're wrong about simplifying the closure - `members[member].id` will continue to change on each pass through the loop.

Comment: This correction still gives me the last button being the one to fire the event.

Answer (score 2):

Well, instead of those workaround you can also use:

```
element.setAtrribute('onClick', 'javascript:functionName(' + parameter + ');');
```

which worked for me and should work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    // Won't work
    //$('div').eq(i)[0].onclick = function() { alert(i) }; // 10


    $('div').eq(i)[0].onclick = (function(id) {
        return function() {
            alert(id)
        };
    })(i);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/74FfE/).

Answer (score 0):

In this block of code:

```
btn.onclick = function (id) {
    return function () {
        addForm(id);
    };
}(members[member].id);
```

You have the syntax wrong - it should be:

```
btn.onclick = (function(id) {
    return function () {
        addForm(id);
    }
})(members[member].id);
```

What this does is *automatically invoke* a new anonymous closure, which has a locally bound copy of `members[member].id` in its `id` parameter, which itself then *returns* a closure which is what's actually bound to `btn.onclick`.

The automatic invokation only happens if you put the outer parenthesis around the closure declaration.

Comment: With your correction only the last button will fire the event.