# Issue with scope and/or click listener in Javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm trying to work out a trivial issue:

```
var setListeners = function()
        {
            for(var i in sliders)
            {
                sliders[i].switchBtn.click(function()
                {
                    alert(i);
                });
            }
        }
```

There are three elements in sliders, so 3 switchBtn's are given a click listener. I expected that clicking the first button would alert with a '0', the second a '1' and the third a '2'. However when I press each button, I just get '2'.

Could someone please point out why the value of i is overridden for each new listener function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since i is outside of the function, you're always referencing the same variable and it's always 2.  You need a closure to get this to work properly:

```
sliders[i].switchBtn.click((function(n){
   return function(){
      alert(n);
   }
})(i));
```

n (was i) is now bound in a closure and your alerts will show properly.

Answer (score 2):

Use a closure so the internal `i` isn't always bound to outer scope (which will be the last value at the end of the loop).

Here the value of `i` is being set to `j`.

```
var setListeners = function()
    {
        for(var i in sliders)
        {
            sliders[i].switchBtn.click((function(j)
            {
                return function() { alert(j) };
            })(i);
        }
    }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/XkKJM/).

Comment: wow, you seriously just edited your post that you made first (and incorrectly) to copy mine character-for-character?  wow...

Comment: @cwolves No, actually, I was testing it on jsFiddle, the similarity is a coincidence I promise you. I've answered this type of question a few times before, so don't assume because I used similar code I stole it.

Comment: k, sorry.  timing was just bad since you edited it right after I posted :)

Comment: @cwolves I noticed you gave the correct answer first. My first answer I forgot the pattern and I quickly remembered about the self invoking function so I went to fiddle to work it out (I try to test all my non trivial JavaScript code before I post it).

Comment: @cwolves||@downvoter So you can remove downvote if you believe me :)

Comment: @downvoter Thanks :) @cwolves Proof that I at least [knew](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350323/adding-events-to-elements-inside-loop-jscript-closures/5350344#5350344) to answer it (sometimes my memory isn't as good as it should be) :)

Comment: As I said, I believe you.  It just looked bad, sorry for accusing you :)

Comment: @cwolves That's OK, just wanted to set the record straight. :)

Comment: meh.  Tried to vote+1 on this as an apology, but it won't let me.

Comment: @cwolves Not necessary, but you can make a trivial edit and then it will let you vote it up. :)

Comment: @alex nope, you have to make a trivial edit, it's your answer :)